# Ipfs. Adding files using http request in meteor

Tags: ipfs, meteor

Good day,

I've spent some time trying to upload file to ipfs using http request (from meteor).

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup
        Meteor.methods({
                "getFile": function(){
                        var results = HTTP.get('http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/object/get', {timeout:5000, params:
                        {"arg": "QmcNHzJeDphzamLVgKq1R3wmFXqw8EbWLVS6qhAPGohobM",
                        "encoding": "json"}});
                        return (results)
                },
                "uploadFile": function(){
                        var results = HTTP.post("http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/add", {timeout:5000, params:{
                        "path": "/home/shultzi/trial.txt",
                        "stream-channels": "true",
                        "arg": "/home/shultzi/trial.txt",
                        //"Content-Type": "multipart/mixed",
                        //"file": "trial.txt"
                        //"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"

                        }, header: {
                        //"Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
                        "enctype": "multipart/form-data",
                        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                        }});
                    return (results)
            }

    })
})
```

The first http request (getFile) works just fine, but when I'm trying to upload the file I constantly get the error message

> "File argument 'path' is required"

. I've tried to modify my http request in many ways, adding `stream-channels` and changing `multipart`, but nothing seems to work.

I know there're some js apis out there, but I really want to work with my own http requests.

I'll highly appreciate any type of help, suggestion or insight you might have!

Comment: FYI: http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/290/87

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this will help or not, but I was able to get the upload working through Postman. The curl looks like this...

```
    curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:5001/api/v0/add \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F image=@/Users/$user/Desktop/cat.jpg
```

I also had problems with the file path argument and the answer is most definitely not pass in a param with 'path' to your file.  If I get it working on Meteor I will paste it back in here.